# How to use espresso to press a setPositiveButton type AlertDialog button

Tags: android, android-espresso

If I want to press ADD button, I tried:

`onView(withText("ADD")).perform(click())`

as well as

```
onView(withText("ADD"))
                .inRoot(isDialog()) 
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(click());
```

But none of them work [well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYg6i.jpg)

Comment: where does the add button come from? is it an android dialog you are displaying?

Comment: @stamanuel ...i wrote....`addGroupDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setView(groupNameEditText).setTitle("Add Group")
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", null)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .create();`

Answer (score 0):

I will offer you to use `uiautomator` for this case, more [info](http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html)

Try to do this

```
Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
UiObject obj = device.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("ADD").clickable(true));
obj.click();
```

Comment: I have also tried                                                                         
 `UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

        // Search for correct button in the dialog.
        UiObject button = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("ADD"));
        button.click();
        /*if (button.exists() && button.isEnabled()) {
            button.click();` This also does not work

Answer (score 0):

The Espresso `withText()` is case sensitive.  You are checking for 'ADD' in the test, but setting the value to 'Add' in the construction of your dialog. If 'ADD' shows up visually in your UI, that's likely due to a style or textallcaps being set on your textView, but Espresso is actually looking for the underlying text value set on the widget.